# Add leading zeros with LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I try to add leading zeros in my ASP MVC application via Linq:

```
int length = 4;
IEnumerable<object> query = [...]
select new
    {
        Seq = a.Seq.ToString("D" + length),
    }).OrderBy(a =>a.Seq).ToList();
```

.. but I receive the following error:

```
Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

What is the correct method to do this?

Comment: Please put your output....

Comment: I dont think prepending zeroes would have any affect on the sorting, so why don't you first do a ToList() and convert them to objects, then you can run your transformations ToString, etc on that objects without any LinqToEntities issues.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think `String.PadLeft` is supported (at least in Linq-To-Sql it works):

```
Seq = a.Seq.PadLeft(length, '0')}
```

If that doesn't work (i cannot test it) you can use [`SqlFunctions.Replicate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.replicate(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Seq = SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", length - a.Seq.ToString().Length) + a.Seq
```

(the length calculation needs to be revised, i hope you get the idea)

Comment: `String.PadLeft()` does not work in Linq to Entities, but `SqlFunctions.Replicate()` does.

Answer (score 3):

From the error you are using LINQ to Entities (with Entity Framework).

Therefore the LINQ expression is being translated into SQL for execution on your database. And there is no directly translation of `ToString(string format)` into SQL.

You have two options:

1. Make use of [`SqlFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): LINQ to Entities knows how to convert these to SQL.
2. Do that part of the processing on the client (perhaps in LINQ to Objects).

However, it appears you are padding a numeric value with zeros and then sorting on it. Why not just sort numerically on the server, and then do the formatting on the client: padding with leading zeros is done to allow digits strings to sorted as if they are numbers, but you already have numbers.

Answer (score 0):

@Richard has the best answer, but this still does not provide a solution.

If you want to sort by date but require that date to be a string (for whatever reason), then convert the date to a string using `SqlFunctions.DatePart`.  But you will need to add leading zero to each part is only 1 digit (except year - already 4 digits).  So use `DBFunctions.Right`.  Simply concatenate a "0" to front of each `DatePart` then trim right to 2 digits using `DBFunction.Right`.

Here is the solution (Use `DBFunctions.Right` method) - This is in VB.Net - easy to convert to c#

```
Let todoDateSort = SqlFunctions.StringConvert(SqlFunctions.DatePart("YEAR", todoDate)) +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(SqlFunctions.DatePart("MONTH", todoDate)), 2) +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(SqlFunctions.DatePart("DAY", todoDate)), 2) +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(SqlFunctions.DatePart("HOUR", todoDate)), 2) +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(SqlFunctions.DatePart("MINUTE", todoDate)), 2) +
    DbFunctions.Right("0" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(SqlFunctions.DatePart("SECOND", todoDate)), 2)
```

Please mark as right answer :)